# Knights tour passing arrays to linked list and more

Tags: c++, arrays, linked-list, stack, knights-tour

I am currently working on the knights tour project.  My goal ultimately is to create this project using backtracking (by implementing stack) and Warnsdorff's heuristic.  I am not allowed to use any libraries that has stack functions already created such as push and pop.  I am also not allowed to resolve the problem using recursion.  With that being said, I am pretty stuck right now and my next big milestone would be to solve the problem by only backtracking.

I am not going to sugar coat this at all, but right now my code is one big mess.  I have pretty much created all the tools I need to make the program run, but now I just need to put all the pieces together.

The following is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class linkedList{

struct node
{
    int data;
    node *next;
};

node *top;

public:
linkedList()
{
    top = NULL;
}
void push(int coordinates)
{
    node *p = new node;
    p -> data = coordinates;
    p -> next = top;
    top = p;
}
int pop()
{
    node *temp = top;
    top = temp -> next;
    return temp -> data;
}
int display()
{
        cout<<"\n"<< top -> data;
        top = top-> next;

}

};


// Linked List ================================================

class Board{
public:
int next;
int status[8][8];
Board();
void print();
};

Board::Board(){

  for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<8; j++){
      status[i][j] = -1;
    }
  }

}//constructor


void Board::print(){

  for (int j=0; j<8; j++){
    for(int i=0; i<8;i++){
      cout << status[i][j] << "   ";
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
  }

}
//BOARD========================================================

class Knight {

 private:
 public:
int vertical[8] = {2,-2,1,-1,2,-2,1,-1}; // possible knight moves x coordinate
int horizontal[8] = {1,1,2,2,-1,-1,-2,-2}; // possible knight move y coordinate
int counter;
int currentPos[2];
Knight();
};

Knight::Knight(){
currentPos[0] = 7; // x-coordiante
currentPos[1] = 7; // y-coordinate
counter = 0;

}//constructor

/* Use this later

int Knight::changePos(int i,int j){

Knight::currentPos[0] = (Knight::currentPos[0] + i);
Knight::currentPos[1] = (Knight::currentPos[1] + j);
counter++;
return counter;
*/

int main(){
    Board b;
    Knight k;

    b.status[k.currentPos[0]][k.currentPos[1]] = k.counter;
    b.print();

    linkedList obj;
    int coordinates;
```

}

So my idea at this point is to do the following:

Create a loop that will change the current position of the knight using the horizontal and vertical array (the possible moves of the knight).  Once the position has changed, the counter will increment and the -1 will be replaced with the current counter value.  When the knight has been moved, the information of the new coordinates needs to be passed to the linked list using the push function I created.  In order to do this, I need to figure out a way to pass an array (x,y) or multiple values to push.  I will also need to create some bound checking which I am currently working on (make sure the knight doesn't move to a spot that he has been to and doesn't go off the board).  Then finally if the knight does get stuck, I need to use the pop function I created to go back a step and try to continue with a different move.

I really really appreciate any help, corrections, places to start or other suggestions that are given!  I am so stuck..

Comment: May I point out that you don't need a dynamically growing linked list for this?  The maximum size of the stack is `N*N` (the total number of squares on the board).  So you can use a single array and the number of moves currently "stacked" into it.

Comment: @BenVoigt Whether he chooses to use 2D coords or flattens the coord plane is irrelevant. He needs a way to store the coords (and possibly more info) for each move so he can effectively backtrack.

Answer (score 0):

Let me get this straight. You're having difficulty implementing the Stack structure that allows you to undo moves.

C++ isn't really my forte but here's how I'd approach the Stack

1. Define a struct that stores the coords (and possibly backtracking info)
2. Update 'node' to store a pointer to an instance of your new struct.
3. Update the 'push()' definition to use it.
4. Update the 'pop()' definition to return it.
5. Profit...